# Add data fromEeditText to double

Tags: android, double

I have an app where the user can enter an amount into an EditText but then I want to be able to add or subtract this to/from a double then be able to display this double with a TextView within another activity.

I'm not sure how to go about this and would appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I also want this data to be kept between app launches/closes.

Comment: For this, you will have to get the data from the Edittext, using edittext.getText.toString, then you will have to parse this string in to double, then you can perform any operation on it.

Comment: And then pass the result as an extra in the Intent to start the other activity

Comment: @PrankulGarg I forgot to mention that I want to be able to save this even if the app is closed.

Comment: for that you will have to use SharedPreferences in the app. you may read about it from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm for persistent storage of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity that accepts the input from the `EditText`:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(yourEditText.getText().toString());
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (adding) {
    value = prefs.getFloat("your.float.key", 0f) + value;
} else {
    value = prefs.getFloat("your.float.key", 0f) - value;
}
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putFloat("your.float.key", value);
editor.apply();
```

In your activity that shows the value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Double value = prefs.getFloat("your.float.key", 0f);
yourTextView.setText(value.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to parse the data from your EditText, you can get a String from an EditText using

```
EditText.getText().toString()
```

and then use some form of

```
Double.parseDouble(String)
Integer.parseInt(String)
```

to get a numeric value from the string, with which you can then use for whatever math you need. After you calculate this value you will want to send it to another Activity via intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
        i.putExtra("KEY", myDouble);
        startActivity(i);
```

to receive the intent in your next activity use

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    Double myDouble = extras.getDouble("KEY");
}
```

and then if you want to save the value you will want to look into SharedPreferences

to save

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putFloat("KEY", myFloat);
editor.commit();
```

to get

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
myFloat = prefs.getFloat("KEY", myFloat);
```